# What is the size limit for Key Strings in Info.plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to set the purpose string for camera access for iPhone. Thus need to set the description in info.plist file for NSCameraUsageDescription key. What should be the message lenght? What is the size limit of the string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there's a formal limit but it has to fit in an alert so don't overdo it. The content will be reviewed by Apple and must be meaningful, though you do not need to go into great detail.